# Rails One-To-Many Associations Not Returning Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I'm new to rails and like many I seem to be having challenges figuring out how ActiveRecord and associations work.

I have three models, user, projects and tasks:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    has_many :tasks
end

Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    belongs_to :user
end

Class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :projects
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Both Projects and Tasks both have the field `user_id`.  Tasks has the field `project_id`.

I expect to be able to look up all the Projects and Tasks through the user.  However, every time I try, I get a blank array even though there are Projects and Tasks:

```
usr = User.find(1)
=> [User id: 1, name: "Some Guy"]
usr.projects
=> []
usr.tasks
=> []
```

It does work when I query for Tasks through Projects:

```
proj = Project.find(1)
=> [#<Project id: 1, user_id: 1, description: "Some Project">]
proj.tasks
=> [#<Task id: 1, user_id: 1, project_id: 1, description: "Do Something">, 
   #<Task id: 2, user_id: 1, project_id: 1, description: "Do another thing">]
```

I believe that the `has_many` and `belongs_to` settings are correct since I have other models connected to the User and they work correctly.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Are the capital letters on the associations a typo?

Comment: so projects have tasks and users have tasks? or do users have projects and the projects have tasks?

Comment: DaveNewton: The "usr.Projects" and "usr.Tasks"?  Yes.  They are, or were, rather.  Corrected.  Thanks.

Comment: c0deNinja: The idea is that Users have projects and projects have tasks.  I included the user_id under tasks for a reason that I'm not quite sure of anymore.  I think so that I could reinforce access to the tasks by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by changing the model associations.  I removed the `belongs_to :user` from the Task model and added a `has_many :through` relationship to the User model:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    has_many :tasks, :through => :projects
end

Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    belongs_to :user
end

Class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :projects
end
```

After restarting the console, I can now pull up tasks that belong to the user in the way I was originally trying:

```
usr = User.find(1)
usr.projects
=>[#<Project id: 1, user_id: 1, description: "Some Project">]
usr.tasks
=>[#<Task id: 1, project_id: 1, description: "Do Another Thing">]
```